# How to allow current over a certain voltage

Tags: led, transistors, phototransistor, ldr

I am new on electronics and i was practicing on transistors. I have a working circuit below. The LDR I use allows current and letting LED smoothly based up to amount of darkness. The Voltage after 2.3 k resistor is 0.7 maximum .. **All i want to do is to let led run on the darkest moment.** So only if it is fully dark the LED must light up .. Not smoothly relative to darkness. What should i do for this ?
**FIX: the source voltage is 6 Volts**

[image: Circuit Scheme]

Comment: Are you willing to consider a 2nd BJT?

Comment: Maybe you should find the LDR's resistance at the darkest moment. And design R2 accordingly. Possibly would be very high value.

Comment: So another 2N2222 will do the job ?

Comment: MITU.. If I increase r2 so how can I provide 0.7 volt 2N2222 transistor requires.?

Comment: Add a comparator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to accurately switch you really need something more active like a comparator. This circuit will pull around 15mA through your LED when the voltage at the top of the LDR exceeds the voltage set by VR1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA3RHi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are other ways to do it with discrete parts, but seriously, you just end up with many more parts and a bigger circuit.